# isKindOfClass test in isEqual method with inheritance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, equality

I've seen many implementions of `isEqual` use `isKindOfClass`, similar to the following:

```
- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)object {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[self class])
        return [self testEqualityFurther];
}
```

If I have a hierarchy like this:

Base : NSObject

Derived : Base

and the Base class were to implement the above method for `isEqual` then, supposing 'b' were an instance of `Base` and 'd' were an instance of `Derived`, [d isEqual:b] may be true, but [b isEqual:d] would never be (because [d isKindOfClass:b] is true, but [b isKindOfClass:d] is never).

Doesn't this violate some law of equality whereby if a is equal to b then b is equal to a?  What if I (as a coder) wanted them to be equal?

For further information, I'm asking this because I want to have a situation similar to this :

```
@interface Base : NSObject
// An abstract class that cannot be init ed
@end

@interface DerivedA : Base
@end

@interface DerivedB : Base
@end
```

If I were to add an `isEqual` method to the Base class (similar to the `isEqual` method above), then I wouldn't be able to get an instance of `DerivedA` to ever be equal to `DerivedB` (because of the `isKindOfClass` test).  If I wanted certain instances of both `DerivedA` and`DerivedB` to be equal, how would I go about it?  What's common practice in this scenario?

Comment: It only "violates some law of equality" because you are using the isKindOfClass as an equality statement(which it isn't).  isKindOfClass isn't the same as saying "is a equal to b"  its saying "is a of class A or anything that inherits from class A".   If you just want a fast check to see if they are both Derived types why not just check for if they inherit from Base (if you know all Derived objects come from base)?

Comment: Hi Alex - what I'm trying to establish is that if the above is used as a test for equality, then it would have to be overridden to compare a derived type to the base type, if it were to have any chance of being equal, wouldn't it?  I would have thought that [object isKindOfClass:[Base class]] is more suitable for isEqual: implementations, but I see [object isKindOfClass:[self class]] more commonly, I think. I was mainly wondering the reason for this.  I guess it depends on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It really depends on what you are looking for.  If you do  [object isKindOfClass:[Derived class]]  that would be for times where the specific class itself has whatever properties/methods you want to ensure are present for later tests.  You would use  [object isKindOfClass:[Base class]]  if you had those properties/methods in a super class and a handful of subclasses were what you were actually using.  So yeah, its really about what you want to achieve.  If the things you use for further testing are common in your super class then use that to determine if you should test further.